# Do I need verifiable shares?

Tags: secret-sharing, 3des

I'm using Shamir's secret sharing in a 2:3 system.
Thus a secret `Key` is split in 3 subkeys `(KeyS:KeyC:KeyT)`

I've 3 entities at play here, `Srv`, `Client`, `Tag`, each one storing one subkey.

In my protocol, `Client` reads `KeyT` from the `Tag` and combine it with its own `KeyC` or query `KeyS` from `Srv` over a secure channel.

I assume I trust the `Client` since its code is verified and I trust the `Srv` as well. I don't trust the `Tag` and the communication between `Client` and `Tag` is not encrypted.

However, the `Tag` can be programmed with the `Key` so that some sort of 3 step authentication between the `Client` and the `Tag` must be run before a secret area can be read from the `Tag` (this authentication does not reveal the secret `Key` on the wire).

So, do I need verifiable share here ?

As far as I understand it, if the `Tag` is under attacker control, and it provides a wrong `KeyT` then the *wrong* derived `Key` computed in the `Client` will not be known to the attacker, since it never leaves the `Client` (even during authentication). Later authentication will then fail, since the `Tag` can not know the `KeyC` from the `Client` then the *wrong* computed `Key`.

Also, if an attacker is able to copy the `Tag` (without the secure area, since she can't know the `Key` beforehand to access it), the `Client` will compute a correct `Key` but this will fail at the authentication step with the `Tag` not knowing this `Key` and thus, unable to provide a proof it does.

The only drawback here would be for the attacker to record the complete `Tag` programming where the `Client` is programming the `Key` in the tag.
I don't think I can do anything against this but the advantage gained by the hacker is kind of useless since such `Key` is random and specific for this `Tag` only.